# When i run my app on my phone and when i run it on android studio emulator the appearance is different

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When i run the app on my phone it looks very different from when i run it in android studio emulator

I tried to constrain layout i tried to run my app on differnt emulator such as pixle 6 ,pixle 7,galaxy s22 and my galaxy s22 real phone. This is what it shows:

the problem is that in the real phone i see that everything bigger , i cant see the last button and the shapes are bigger and the pictures are bigger ,but on the emulator and the xml file everything look ok.

i tried few emulator and few phones:

this is the version of each emulator:
galaxy s22 emulator: android 13.0
pixle 6 android 13.0

real phone:
samsung galaxy s22 version 13.0
samsung a8 version 9

one more thing , i saw when i change the dp to 420 in my phone the app looks normal like it needs to like in the xml , but when i keep it 360 dp its like in the picture , very big and cant see the last button

my emulator is 420 dp all of them.

android studio emulator:[galaxy s22 skin for android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJNzt.png)

and this is how it shown in my galaxy s22 real phone[My real galaxy s22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN43K.jpg)

I tried using guideline also but it didnt help.

The goal here is to achieve that the appearance of the app in my phone will look like in the android studio emulator.

this is my xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sky"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sky"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/emailButton"
        android:layout_width="220sp"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Sign up with email"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_selector"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/googleButton" />


    <!--    <ImageView-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/ASIM_logo_no_back"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="300sp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="130sp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginTop="56sp"-->
    <!--        android:src="@drawable/main_logo"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sky" />-->

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="220sp"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/googleButton"
        android:layout_width="220sp"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Continue with google"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_selector"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/people_gym" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/people_gym"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gym_people"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/asim" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/asim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/staatliches_regular"
            android:text="ASIM"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="90sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/righteous_regular"
            android:text="When fitness meets AI"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline3"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0sp" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline4"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="0sp" />-->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.00" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0" />

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline7"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="56dp" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline8"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="728dp" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline9"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="503dp" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline10"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="208dp" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline11"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="317sp" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline12"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="vertical"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="95dp" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/guideline13"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="vertical"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="96dp" />-->


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i connect it to the computer with cable and the android studio immediately recognize it and when i run in the android studio it shows me in my phone

Comment: becuase when i run the emulator on android studio i takes a long time untill it runs and it makes my computer work slow , so i started using my phone as emulator (android studio has an option for this). The problem is when i run my phone as emulator is shows the xml file differnt then when i use the android studio emulator

Comment: sorry my bad , you right ,i meant that u have an option that allows you to run the app you created in android studio on your phone, the problem when i run the app on my phone it looks different then when i run it on emulator of the android studio

Comment: How can i fix the problem that i have ?

Comment: If you can check now and tell me if you understand what i wrote , if you understand the problem ? if not i try to edit again

Comment: I edited again , and i mentioned versions and dp, the dp in my phone is 360 and in the emulator is 420

Comment: How can i change the dp of the xml or the emulator ?

Comment: I have no idea. And i'm already puzzled by `when i change the dp to 420 in my phone`. How the world would you do that? But i think you should tackle it differently and make a layout that forces the three buttons to the bottom of the sreen all visible and the rest like the imageview should adapt to that. But i'm not a gui programmer so dont ask me.

Comment: you can use for developers in your android phone and change it there , this is only thing that helped me but it makes my phone look weird ,this is why i got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ensures that the preview in the emulator corresponds exactly to the screen of your smartphone:

1. Connect your smartphone to the PC.
2. Select in the menus `Tools` ➜ `Device Manager` and select `⋮` in the line of your **physical** smartphone (see picture).
3. Select `View Details` and make a note of the `resolution (px)`. (Note: These figures may differ from the description of your smartphone!)
4. Use `+` to create a **virtual** device with exactly this resolution and select this virtual device for the emulator.

[image]