# Get fullscreen width and height on android

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen

I'm trying to get the screen size when using a fullscreen app on android. This is what I'm doing:

```java
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
               
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
float density = displayMetrics.density;

WIDTH = width/density;
HEIGHT = height/density;
```

My problem is that on some devices, I get a black border on the top and the screen extends at the bottom (there is a small offset). It doesn't look like a hardware problem as other apps on my phone run at fullscreen normally. [Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURyp.png)

Is there anything I can do? Thanks

Comment: Can you check the theme which you are setting in manifest file

Comment: @Nadeem, I don't have any themes in my android manifest file

Comment: how is that possible there should be a code android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" like this isnt there that

Comment: @Nadeem, here is the manifest file: https://pastebin.com/GFXgMMfZ. I'm currently using javafxports but it's still android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by mixing some of the answers here on stackoverflow. This is what I did:

- According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228215/13088461) I added:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

- I added this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

- And this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

The only problem, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77805578/13088461) by @Cloverleaf was that I used some deprecated APIs. Now with this changes and by using the code for API 30 it works fine, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv30t.png).

Answer (score 2):

The method `getRealMetrics` is deprecated as of API 31, see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display). Use this instead (for API 30+):

```java
WindowMetrics metrics = this.getSystemService(WindowManager.class).getCurrentWindowMetrics();
int width = metrics.getBounds().width();
int height = metrics.getBounds().height();
float density = metrics.getDensity(); //This line even requires API 34, otherwise your method from above.
```

Comment: It looks like that getMetrics() is deprecated too. Anyway I tried your solution, much better but I still get a white empty space at the bottom on where the navigation buttons should be.

Comment: You're right, I was a bit too quick with my answer. But I have corrected it and everything should work now.

Comment: I tried it and tried also what the android documentation said at the link you provided but I still get the same result. The width and the height that I get are still the same. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Hm, strange. My (edited) code works on my smartphone, and I also found this snippet twice in Kotlin on StackOverflow. It should really specify the physical dimensions of the screen. But the link I mentioned also says "The real display area may be smaller than the physical size of the display in a few scenarios." Maybe this is such a case. But without code and device, the cause is very difficult to find.

Comment: Continued: Do you know the physical height of the screen of that device? (If not, look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77661818/22820043). Is that the same number as my/your code provides? If so, the error is 100% somewhere else. If not, what are the two numbers?

Comment: The size of my device, I checked it in the device information with droidInfo, it's 720x1600. Both my code and yours gives me the same size (720x1600) but I divide it by the density so I get 411x914. Do you believe that the error is somewhere else? I guess that the size is ok, the app's display is just offsetted.

Comment: The fact is: Your code already solves the problem posed in the title of your question, the code is just deprecated. The undesired effect must therefore take place in the further processing of the WIDTH and HEIGHT numbers, but I can't say anything about this without further information.